# Using static in a recursive function

Tags: c, binary

I came across the following in writing a recursive function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void bin_r(unsigned int n)
{
    static int s;
    s++;
    printf("%d", s);
    if (n>1) 
    {
        bin_r(n>>1);
    }
    printf("%d", s);
    // ...
}

int main(void) {bin_r(1777);}
```

> 12345678910111111111111111111111111

It seems like the 'static'-ness of the variable `s` works as (I) expected before the recursive function call, but after it it seems to reinitialize it every time. What would be an explanation of what's going on here?

Here's an example of the code if you want to run it: https://onlinegdb.com/znV72a6Gw

Comment: See [mcve] .....

Comment: @user3386109 hm? It works as is. I included a link to the code where you can run it.

Comment: The [mcve] must be in the question itself. Kindly read the link that I have now posted twice.

Comment: @user3386109 added.

Comment: As the recursion unwinds, it prints `11` 11 times.

Comment: I don't see any evidence of reinitialization.  The output is a concatenation of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, followed by a bunch more 11s, exactly as I would expect for the example program presented.

Comment: Add a `\n` to your `printf`s

Comment: @JohnBollinger right -- why does that happen though? And is there a way to keep the static value as it would be before the recursive call (going from 1 to 11) via a static var, or I'd need to use something else for that?

Comment: Why does that differ from your expectation, @David542?  As a `static` variable declared without an initializer, `s` is automatically initialized to 0 at the start of the program.  At each step down the recursion series, that (one) `s` is incremented and then printed.  On the way back up, the final value is printed at each level. 1777 is between 2^10 and 2^11, so 11 levels of recursion is to be expected.

Comment: @JohnBollinger ok I think in asking this question and your feedback I was able to get a working example which shows where I was tripping up. Do you want to look at my answer and let me know if that seems like it's answering things correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `bin_r` again, before the second printf. Meaning, only when the condition `(n>1)` is true, will the recursion be terminated and the stack can unwind, executing the second printf [however many levels of recursion you have] times without increasing s further.

In your example, you have 11 levels of recursion, which is why you get 11 times "11" printed after the termination condition is met.

Answer (score 2):

The question asks:

> It seems like the 'static'-ness of the variable s works as (I)
> expected before the recursive function call, but after it it seems to
> reinitialize it every time. What would be an explanation of what's
> going on here?

As I remarked in comments, I see no evidence of reinitialization.  As a `static` variable declared without an initializer, `s` is automatically initialized to 0 at the start of the program. At each step down the recursion series, `s` (of which there is only one, not one per call) is incremented and then printed.  The input 1777 is between 2<sup>10</sup> and 2<sup>11</sup>, so the particular function given recurses to depth 11.  That produces

```
1234567891011
```

on the way down.  On the way back up, `s`, whose value is then 11, is printed again at each level without further modification, for an additional

```
1111111111111111111111
```

In comments you additionally inquired:

> And is there a way to keep the static value as it would be before the recursive call (going from 1 to 11) via a static var, or I'd need to use something else for that?

The whole point of a static local variable is that it represents a single object accessed by all executions of the function.  That object's lifetime is the same as the whole program's, and, like any object, it retains its last-stored value until a new one is stored or its lifetime ends.  So no, there is no way to make it automatically reset after the topmost call of your recursion terminates.  Moreover, being declared inside a function, it has no linkage, so it cannot be directly modified from outside the function.

Generally speaking, variables with static storage duration do not play well with recursion.  They are incompatible with recursive functions that access them being used in multi-threaded programs, and those declared at block scope, such as your `s`, are difficult to reset from outside the block in which they are declared.

It would be possible to structure your `bin_r()` to address the latter issue, maybe like so:

```
void bin_r(unsigned int n, _Bool top) {
    static int s;

    s = top ? 1 : (s + 1);
   
    printf("%d", s);
    if (n>1) {
        bin_r(n>>1, 0);
    }
    printf("%d", s);
}
```

Of course, that requires the caller of the top-level execution to pass 1 to signal the function to reset the variable.  If you don't like that then you could change that version of `bin_r` to a helper function, and provide a separate, non-recursive function to perform the top-level call correctly.

But if you're going to do that, then why not just get rid of the static variable while you're at it, maybe something like this:

```
void bin_r(unsigned int n, int *s) {
    (*s)++;
    printf("%d", *s);
    if (n>1) {
        bin_r(n>>1, s);
    }
    printf("%d", *s);
}
```

Again, provide a one-arg wrapper for that if you like.  Now you're thread-safe, and you have full control.

Comment: one question, in the first code segment why is `top` always set to zero? `bin_r(n>>1, 0);` ? Is that supposed to be `s` instead of `0` ?

Comment: @David542, because the code was wrong. See the updated code.  Passing `s` would be another possibility, similar to the latter code, but then it's pointless to have both `s` and `top`.

Comment: thanks, and in the second version, what would be the advantage of passing it as a pointer `int *s` instead of `int s`. Why would someone want the return value / side effect, for example?

Comment: Why would someone want to print the value, @David542?  Do you not suppose that if it's desirable for someone to print it, then it might not be desirable to that person or another to store the value in memory?  But it is not essential to use a pointer.  I wrote the code that way to be more analogous to your original.  With the pointer, there is again only one object in which the recursion level is recorded.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers/comments are correct here, but here is a basic example to show two different ways that `static` variables may be used in a basic recursive function: before and after the self-function call:

- `static int digits` -- used/incremented before the recursive function call.
- `static int sep` -- used/incremented after the recursive function call.

```
void bin_r(unsigned int n)
{
    // how many total digits -- this will be finished before unwinding the stack
    // here we will increment digits BEFORE the function call, so when the stack
    // is unwound we have the full length / number of digits
    static int digits, sep;
    if (digits==0) printf("%d --> ", n);
    digits++;   

    if (n>1) 
        bin_r(n>>1, level);
    putchar((n&1)==0? '0' : '1'); // == has higher precedence than &

    // unwinding the stack -- separate every four digits from RTL, newline at end
    // here we will increment sep AFTER the function call, so now that we unwind
    // the stack, it will essentially be counting how many frames have been unwound.
    sep ++;
    if (!((digits-sep)%4) && digits != sep) putchar(' ');
    if (digits==sep) {
        putchar('\n');
        digits = sep = 0; // reset statics
    }
}
```

And here we use both methods to get our output:

> 1777 --> 110 1111 0001

which is combined together in this line to separate the binary digits every four from right-to-left:

```
if (!((digits-sep)%4) ...
```

Comment: This is a bit offtopic, but really using static variables in recursive functions is terrible style, and pretty well never necessary. For one thing, static variables are only initialised once. What happens if you want to call your recursive function twice in a program? Or from a thread?

Comment: @rici yea I'm learning that a bit...I put a line at the end to reset it. Is it still considered bad practice with something like that? Obviously would not be thread-safe...

Comment: I would always consider it bad style. It might have some pedagogic value but in production code it's a serious code smell. (Of course, many people think that recursive functions are bad style, but that's a different issue. Personally, I'm fine with recursive function if the recursion depth is limited.)

Comment: Modifiable objects with static storage duration have at least mild code smell in general.  This would include those that some call "global variables".  The ones that additionally are declared at block scope have worse smell.  They are a key reason why functions such as `strtok()` and `rand()` are problematic, and why versions of those that do not rely on static data were standardized.  Static-duration objects that are declared at lock scope inside recursive functions are positively stinky.